# Deploy To Azure Container Apps is Missing from Publish Targets in VS2022

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2022, azure-container-apps

I'm following the [deployment tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/deploy-visual-studio) for a simple BackgroundService I created with Docker Support Enabled, but when I get to the Section entitled "Create the Resources", I do not have the proper publish targets available.  The tutorial shows many options, including "Azure Container Apps (Preview)", but I do not have that option.  I do have all of [the prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/deploy-visual-studio#prerequisites) listed.  The targetOS in the project file is linux `<DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>`.

Targets from Tutorial Page
[image: Tutorial publish targets]

Targets on my local machine
[image: My local publish targets]

VS Info

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022
Version 17.1.1
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.1.1+32228.430
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04161

Installed Version: Professional

.NET Core Debugging with WSL   1.0
.NET Core Debugging with WSL

ADL Tools Service Provider   1.0
This package contains services used by Data Lake tools

ASA Service Provider   1.0

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019   17.1.358.51495
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2019   17.1.358.51495
For additional information, visit https://www.asp.net/

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.1.358.51495
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   17.1.358.51495
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio

C# Tools   4.1.0-5.22109.6+0c82c4114a4e4b8b723b915eee3b13261db6717f
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Fabric.DiagnosticEvents   1.0
Fabric Diagnostic Events

Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Hive query

Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio   17.0
Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio

Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Azure Stream Analytics

Microsoft Azure Tools for Visual Studio   2.9
Support for Azure Cloud Services projects

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Microsoft Library Manager   2.1.161+abc97ecc7d.RR
Install client-side libraries easily to any web project

Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.2
Develop, run, validate your ASP.NET Core applications in the target environment. F5 your application directly into a container with debugging, or CTRL + F5 to edit & refresh your app without having to rebuild the container.

Node.js Tools   1.5.40105.1 Commit Hash:1822ee94b29c6cf748a19825f14cc26d30b0b871
Adds support for developing and debugging Node.js apps in Visual Studio

NuGet Package Manager   6.1.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

Razor (ASP.NET Core)   17.0.0.2206201+62a2c1d6162f828801565a7ca26d9d48b810a05b
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

SQL Server Data Tools   17.0.62201.12090
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0
Hosting json editor into a tool window

TypeScript Tools   17.0.1229.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   4.1.0-5.22109.6+0c82c4114a4e4b8b723b915eee3b13261db6717f
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools   17.1.0-beta.21610.4+07b5673e4f2fa7630e78abe37f16b372353a7242
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0
Interop layer for hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio

Visual Studio Container Tools Extensions   1.0
View, manage, and diagnose containers within Visual Studio.

Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2
AI-assisted development for Visual Studio.

Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for Containers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Visual Studio version `17.2.1` vs `17.1.1` (your mentioned version). Refer [announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022-17-2-is-now-available/#azure-development).

Comment: Thanks @JJ.  I added an issue to their docs repo to fix this prerequisites.  https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/93252